# Integral with exponent and trigonometric functions

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, trigonometric-integrals

How do I solve the following integral?
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cos x} \cos \left( 3x + \frac{1}{2} \sin x \right) dx
$$

I suppose this can be solved with integrating by parts and building the equation for $I$ but cannot find the right way to do this

Comment: Surprising or not, the antiderivative does exist. Are you sure about the integrand ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici However, I've no idea how to find the closed form of the antiderivative for this case

Comment: It is a monster ! Have you access to a CAS ?

Comment: I tried WolframAlpha but it didn't cope with this task

Comment: Show that
$$I = \frac 1 2 \operatorname {Re} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-3 i x - e^{i x}/2} dx,$$
then take $z = e^{i x}$.

Comment: @Maxim thanks, after this change of variable $I$ may be solved with computing a residue. Please, put your advice as an answer and I'll mark it as a correct one

Answer (score 1):

I shall give you the result obtained after a lot of simplifications of the result provided by a CAS.
$$J = \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cos (x)} \cos \left( 3x + \frac{1}{2} \sin (x) \right)\, dx$$
$$J=\color{red}{\frac{i}{96}  \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{e^{i
   x}}{2} \right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{e^{-i x}}{2}\right)\right)}+$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{24} \left(\sin \left(x+\frac{\sin (x)}{2}\right)-2 \sin
   \left(2x+\frac{\sin (x)}{2} \right)+8 \sin \left(3x+\frac{\sin
   (x)}{2} \right)\right) \times }$$ $$\color{blue}{\left(\cosh \left(\frac{\cos (x)}{2}\right)-\sinh
   \left(\frac{\cos (x)}{2}\right)\right)}$$ Integrated between $0$ and $\pi$, the $\color{blue}{\text{blue term}}$ is obviously zero (because of the sines) and what is left is to evaluate  the
$\color{red}{\text{red term}}$. So, for the definite integral, we are left with
$$I =\color{green}{ \int_0^{\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cos (x)} \cos \left( 3x + \frac{1}{2} \sin (x) \right) dx=-\frac \pi{48} }$$

This has been check by numerical integration.

Comment: Thanks! As @Maxim has pointed out, this integral may be solved by switching to the complex contour integral

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov. This is what I was expecting (and hoping for you) but I am so bad with contour integrals (and with so many other domains) !